# How to know if this entity diagram is properly normalized? With the picture below, would it be ok to build a simple database?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, entity, entity-relationship

[Ticket Booking Entity Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxcG3.jpg)

I am practicing to build databases. I just modeled this in draw.io before building a physical model. However, I am confused if this model is a proper one. What should be the best way to implement this ticket booking database? What aspect of this model needs to be changed, or what action of design should not be followed? Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

No, this model wouldn't work.

In your model tickets are associated with the cinema, which doesn't make sense.

Your timings also have nothing to do with Movie. While you've got the right ID there your relationship lines are a bit wonky.

There are a couple of different ways of doing it, but based on what you've got so far I'd go for something along these lines:

[image: Quick sketch of my solution]

The way to think about it is what has what: A Cinema has times that it can show movies. A movie is shown at a time. A time has seats that are sold via tickets to users. You can certianly put the MovieID into the Tickets or Seats table for your foriegn keys, but the above is how I see the main relationships going.

Depending on how you want to model it you could make it that cinemas have movies, and movies have timings. I went with Cinemas having timings, because that feels more right to me. You may have a different opinion.

Comment: Often a cinema can show multiple movies at the same time, and new releases will show on more than one screen with staggered start times. A cinema would have a list of movies currently being exhibited. It might also have a collection of various _theaters_ (or _screens_) where the movies are shown. Each _theater_ has its own seating plan that would apply to any movie shown there.

Comment: @HABO Ha, that is a really good point, and really shows the last time I went and saw a movie on the big screen :)